# Revoke multiple celery tasks

Tags: celery, celery-task

I want to revoke multiple tasks from celery.
From official docs, they suggested below approach.
Is there any limit for this? Because i will get around 10k or 100k tasks to revoked.

```
>>> app.control.revoke([
...    '7993b0aa-1f0b-4780-9af0-c47c0858b3f2',
...    'f565793e-b041-4b2b-9ca4-dca22762a55d',
...    'd9d35e03-2997-42d0-a13e-64a66b88a618',
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a limit.  But please note the [limitations around task revocation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/workers.html#revoke-revoking-tasks).  In particular, this list of task IDs will be kept in memory or on disk, so there may be some amount of memory or disk overhead.

Comment: Celery has undocumented limit on flagged as revoked tasks. Details are in my answer.

Comment: Does celery ever reset this list or can revoke IDs be removed from the list after some period of time?  

If you hit the 50,000 limit and you are persisting your list by using the statedb parameter, can you ever revoke another task?

Answer (score 1):

There is an undocumented limit in max 50000 flagged as revoked tasks stored in worker memory (as min for Celery 4.3 and 5.2)

Meaning that you can't handle more than 50000 flagged as revoked tasks per worker. Running Celery cluster will not help also.

While task discarded it removed from `celery.worker.state.revoked` and decrement `flagged as revoked` counter by one.

Related Celery source code [celery.worker.state](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/_modules/celery/worker/state.html)

**Experimental approval:**

1. Run celery worker [optionally with --statedb path to create a file]:

```
$ celery worker --statedb=STATE_DB_FILEPATH
```

2. Revoke 60000 tasks (by generated ids) in celery shell:

```
$ celery shell
>> from uuid import uuid4
>> REVOKE_TASK_NUMBER = 60000
>> celery.control.revoke([str(uuid4()) for i in range(REVOKE_TASK_NUMBER)])
```

3. Validate that worker stores only 50000 revoked ids:

```
$ celery inspect revoked | wc -l
50003
```

4. Shutdown the worker and validate that `statedb` stores only 50000 records (if created clean):

```py
import zlib
import shelve

from kombu.serialization import pickle, pickle_protocol

filename=STATE_DB_FILEPATH

db = shelve.open(filename, protocol=pickle_protocol)
data = pickle.loads(zlib.decompress(db['zrevoked']))
print(len(data))

>> 50000
```